# ElGamal variant

Tags: public-key, elgamal-encryption

I came across this problem, while currently reading "Introduction to Modern Cryptography" by Katz and Lindell.
I am new to crypto and just trying to go through the book and solve the exercises, unfortunately, got stuck at this one.

Consider the following public-key encryption scheme. 
The public key is $(G, q, g, h)$ and the private key is $x$, generated exactly as in the El-Gamal encryption scheme. In order to encrypt a bit b, the sender does the following:

- If $b = 0$ then choose a uniform $y ∈ Z_{q}$ and compute $c_{1} := g^{y}$ and $c_{2} := h^{y}$. The ciphertext is $(c_{1} , c_{2}) $.
- If $b = 1$ then choose independent uniform $y,z ∈ Z_{q}$ , compute $c_1 := g^{y}$ and $c_{2} := g^{z}$ , and set the ciphertext equal to $(c_{1},c_{2})$.

Show  that  it  is  possible  to  decrypt  efficiently  given  knowledge  of
$x$.

Would appreciate some help

Comment: **Hint 1:** take $x$-th power of $c_1$.

Comment: Thanks, that helped for b=0! Still not sure how to approach for the case b=1 though.

Comment: So you get equality right?

Comment: Yes, I do for b=0.

Comment: Then if there is no equality it means?

Comment: binary case, equal = 0, not equal =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the bit plaintext from $(c_1,c_2)$ take $x$-th power of the $c_1$. There are two options that we don't know

1. $(c_1,c_2) = (g^y,h^y)$ then $(c_1^x,c_2) = (g^{xy},g^{xy})$
2. $(c_1,c_2) = (g^y,g^z)$ then $(c_1^x,c_2) = (g^{xy},g^{z})$

Now check whether $c_1^x = c_2$ or not.

- If they are equal then than bit $b=0$
- If they are not equal than bit $b=1$.

There is a small chance that we will have $g^{xy}=g^{z}$ as false $b=0$. The probability of this event is $1/g$.

**The cost of operation:** if we use Left-to-right binary method for modular exponentiation than the cost is $\mathcal{O}(\log(x))$, therefore, it is efficient.

Comment: Note: the question is solved by OP with the hints.